# SQL pivot query data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Can someone show me the query. I have a table with the below data which I wish to pivot.

```
Name    Ride    Hour
Abbas   Falls   1
Abbas   Falls   2
Abbas   Falls   3
Shiraz  Falls   1
Shiraz  Falls   2
Shiraz  Falls   3
Adnan   Falls   1
Adnan   Falls   2
Adnan   Falls   3
Adnan   Falls   4
Abbas   Lunch   4
Shiraz  Lunch   4
Adnan   Lunch   5
Abbas   Jolly   5
Shiraz  Jolly   5
Abbas   Jolly   6
Shiraz  Jolly   6
Adnan   Jolly   6
```

I want to convert it to look like this:

```
Name    1       2       3       4       5       6
Abbas   falls   falls   falls   Lunch   Jolly   Jolly
Shiraz  falls   falls   falls   Lunch   Jolly   Jolly
Adnan   falls   falls   falls   falls   Lunch   Jolly
```

I wrote this but it doesn't do the job

```
 SELECT *
 FROM
 (SELECT *
    FROM _Test) as test
 PIVOT
(
COUNT(ride)
FOR hour IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6])
) AS PivotTable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `MAX` instead of `COUNT`:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM (SELECT *
       FROM Test) as test
 PIVOT (
   MAX(ride)
   FOR hour IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6])) AS PivotTable
```

Comment: Im sorry that was a slip, I corrected it. Thank you again